# Lenovo Y510P Not Shifting to AC Adapter After a Disconnection

Tags: laptop, battery, power, lenovo-laptop

I am using this laptop from last three years. It was working fine till yesterday before I performed battery gauge Reset. Now I am facing issue.

When I disconnect AC Adapter and Reconnect it to Laptop. Laptop doesn't shift to AC supply and keep draining battery continuously without shifting to AC Power.

It Only Shift to AC Power by Following Steps.

- Remove Battery from Laptop
- Remove AC Adapter from Socket
- Press Power Button for 30 seconds
- Put AC Adapter in Socket and Laptop and Release Power Button
- Then Computer Will Turn On using AC Adapter
- Insert Battery After that Laptop Charges Battery as Normal Laptop however After disconnection I have to do all this again.

Above way is very incontinent. Every time when I have to remove AC Adapter or there is a power cutoff.

Note:
- I am using windows 10 from many months it was okay on windows 10 before.
- My Settings and version of power management has no issues.
- My AC Adapter is fine. It has no issues.
- I am using Latest BIOS available on Lenovo Site
- I tried to update battery firmware however couldn’t find it.

Please suggest me some solution ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, some people has the same issue with you about Lenovo Y Series. We could boot into Safe Mode to check if the issue still insists. Some people reinstall the Network card driver and graphic driver to fix.
Meanwhile, it was working fine till yesterday. We could perform a Clean Boot to avoid the effect of third party software. Or trying to use system restore.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on Y510p after I calibrated the battery using Lenovo energy management software. It's a hardware issue. Some problem with motherboard. Please check on YouTube. A video is available which instructs how replace some capacitor on motherboard to solve the issue.